# Unable to read csv from S3 presigned url directly in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, sourceforge-appscript

Hi is there anyway to open csv file from s3 presigned url in a script rather than downloading it from browser! I recieve a presigned s3 url every hour on gmail. I have to download it manually everytime. I decided to automate the process by scraping my emails, have reached the step where I am able to get the fresh presigned link but unable to open the csv file, rather it returns a script. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` to perform a `GET` request.

From the [AWS page explaining boto3 and presigned URLs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html):

> The user can download the S3 object by entering the presigned URL in a browser. A program or HTML page can download the S3 object by using the presigned URL as part of an HTTP GET request.

> The following code demonstrates using the Python requests package to perform a GET request.

```
import requests    # To install: pip install requests

url = create_presigned_url('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME')
if url is not None:
    response = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this but it is returning html rather than returning csv.

Comment: I don't believe that it's HTML that lives at the other end of a presigned URL, I mean... unless HTML is stored in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it directly using pandas `read_csv`. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

[image]

So you can simply:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://...')
```

Comment: Hi tankthinks, I ahve tried this as well but it always shows parsing error.

Comment: @AkshitaBhardwaj, is that a problem with the file contents itself? What is the error?

Comment: @AkshitaBhardwaj, based off of this comment and your response to the other solution, I think you are likely using the wrong URL. The url you need to pass to either solution should look something like `https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object path>?<lots of aws security query parameters>`

Comment: Omg thank you so much! Yeah the format of url was different! This really helped ! thanks again